# Bluetooth connected but not usable on startup

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, gentoo

My BT keyboard is Filco 61. I can pair and connect it with my Gentoo system. But after a restart, the keyboard appears to be not usable, even though the system shows it is connected.

I have to disconnect then connect the keyboard to make it function.

I am not sure if it has something to do with my system or my keyboard. The keyboard works fine with Windows 10.

My Gentoo uses *bluez* from http://www.bluez.org to setup the device.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/bluetooth/input.conf should be set to true, else a HID bluetooth will not be handled in userspace by default.

If it's already set to true, it might be starting as HCI instead of HID, which needs another correction as an udev rule.